# Null pointer error when attempting to get data from MDataHandle passed to a helper function in custom node (Maya 2016 SP6, Python API)

Tags: python, python-2.7, maya, maya-api

I'm having an issue where the MObject returned by MDataHandle.data() is a null pointer when called from within a helper function.

I have a custom node with a couple of generic attributes (supports kDouble, k3Double, and k3Float) which need to be processed differently based on whether they are simple numeric data versus array data. I created a helper function defined as a @classmethod within my custom node class, which is used to extract data as needed from the generic attributes. An MDataHandle to the appropriate attribute is passed to the function (would it be better to pass the MDataBlock..?) and the attribute is checked with isGeneric(). If it is found be non-numeric (in this case, an array), the MDataHandle.data() function is called in order to get an MObject to attach to a MFnNumericData object, which is where the issue appears.

```
@classmethod
def getDataHandleValue(obj, dataHandle):

    print 'getDataHandleValue called'  # DEBUG

    # Script util objects for creating pointers
    isNumericUtil = OpenMaya.MScriptUtil(False)
    isNullUtil = OpenMaya.MScriptUtil(False)

    isNumericPtr = isNumericUtil.asBoolPtr()
    isNullPtr = isNullUtil.asBoolPtr()

    if dataHandle.isGeneric(isNumericPtr, isNullPtr):

        if isNumericUtil.getBool(isNumericPtr):

            print 'Generic data is numeric'  # DEBUG

            return dataHandle.asGenericDouble()

        else:

            print 'Generic data is not numeric'  # DEBUG

            dataObj = dataHandle.data()

            print 'Got data object'  # DEBUG

            nDataFn = OpenMaya.MFnNumericData()

            print 'Attempting to set object...'  # DEBUG
            nDataFn.setObject(dataObj)

            val0 = 0.0
            val1 = 0.0
            val2 = 0.0

            print [val0, val1, val2]  # DEBUG

            nDataFn.getData3Double(val0, val1, val2)

            return [val0, val1, val2]

    else:

        raise ValueError('Data handle to non-generic attribute')
```

When I attempt to create the function set by passing the MObject from the MDataHandle.data() I get a null pointer error...

I am wondering if there is some sort of scope issue, since the documentation mentions that the MDataBlock is only valid during the compute function of the node, but I would think a helper function running within the compute function would be okay.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Update: It looks like my issue may be that the generic attributes have not been initialized to a default value, thus, the datahandle to the attribute is a null pointer. If so, what is the best way to set a default value for generic attributes?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, getting an MDataHandle to a generic attribute that has not been initialized with some value results in a Null pointer being returned.